# iOS - Connect to a WiFi with password

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone-privateapi, ssid

Is it possible to connect to a Wireless access point with all the private information (ssid and password) provided? It is okay even with a private framework. I am not releasing it in appstore so I just want to know if it can be done or not in iOS.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I would also like to know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:
[Where do I find iOS Obj-C code to scan and connect to wifi (private API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725553/where-do-i-find-ios-obj-c-code-to-scan-and-connect-to-wifi-private-api)

You'll need a jailbroken device.
I tested it on iOS 5,6, and 7.