# connect to a specific wifi programmatically in ios with a given SSID and Password

Tags: ios, iphone

is it possible to make an application connect to a wifi spot in ios, provided that the app knows the Name/SSID and password.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to what you see here and other places, you can do it.  But it's not pretty.  It's an enterprise admin thing, but anyone can do it.  Look up "Connection Profiles."  Comcast does this in their iOS app to setup their hotspots for you, for example.

Basically, it's an XML document that you get the device to ingest via Safari or Mail.  There's a lot of tricks to it and the user experience isn't great, but I can confirm that it works in iOS 10 and it doesn't require jailbreaking.  You use Configurator to generate the XML, and I suggest [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338035/installing-a-configuration-profile-on-iphone-programmatically) for serving it, and [this blog](http://blog.markhorgan.com/?p=701) for querying if it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to submit the app to the Appstore, then yes, you can do that.
You'll need a jailbroken device.
here are the details:

[Where do I find iOS Obj-C code to scan and connect to wifi (private API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725553/where-do-i-find-ios-obj-c-code-to-scan-and-connect-to-wifi-private-api)